# For loop prints wrong branch of if-else statement first

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, settimeout, contains

the following code is just to test the functionality

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

  if(i==4){
    console.log(document.getElementById("loading").classList.contains("invisible"));
    break;
  }else{
    (function(i){ 
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i) }, i*1000);
    })(i);
  }
  
}
/*this basically gives true or false as result
document.getElementById("loading").classList.contains("invisible")*/
```

this is the console log

```
false
1
2
3
```

Now my question is how & why am I getting false even if the if condition "(1==4)" is not true and why doesn't the code break when the first part of if statement is executed to get false

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous callback function passed to `setTimeout` is invoked asynchronously. Hence, it may be the case that the `console.log` for `i==4` is evaluated before the other `console.log` is evaluated.